# Geetest v4 captcha

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha, 2captcha, bypass

I'm trying to solve Geetest v4 with 2captcha and this data comes:

```
{'captchaId': '74816752541', 'code': '{"captcha_id":"6b7d5e7c8c08dae2c53e0a047be61d8f","lot_number":"f0c70b48017b4255b0f3cbd9bec3f9b3","pass_token":"b1b81aeb3afc70e459e2d5852d8aec0222bf35889c3f4da3acead6ec3199b7c6","gen_time":"1697837298","captcha_output":"etLA6K7pvRsEVzt0zlxesPVbthaZWVa8o1Pqe0BXP9qcE8FFKgLlMKh6SEQWqpcoZtF0_djCnN01OWSBG-Y2IIq8ZdH86W-OH7FESeaWs7_ntbZebfl3XvJXf2QC8yn4ot6STeyXGi8A4jq73roLXkWzErro-qYbOmnO0rLw-S04zLZmFjDjEtlJKufNtIsoi1-5ik0lFsPLiu1vz5ogS8VXIEiqvlXAK4_KzKuD9gKpEgdM8vswKcJCI4Ak8bIPIZyyFH2x7stR2qpA_ZzWJg=="}
```

However, I could not find where to use this data. I thought about giving this data to the initGeetest4 method, but it also requires an extra "callback" parameter and I don't know what value I should enter in the parameter. What should I do? Where do I enter the data?

Btw, I am using selenium in the project.

I'm trying to solve this type of captcha:
[captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oszUF.png)

I tried the initGeetest4 method and examined the html codes of the box you see in the image and tried to find an invisible input, but it did not exist.